# ajax datepicker

Tags: php, ajax, datepicker

In attachment File Have ziped file for Ajax Datepicker. The Code is working but i have some problem.

if i want to use it with php, how can i know where is the $_POST name .

Code :

```
<div id="widget"><div id="widgetField" style="width: 290px; height: 26px"> <span>28 July, 2008 &divide; 31 July, 2008</span> <a href="#">Select date range</a>      </div>      <div id="widgetCalendar">       </div>      </div>
```

Between   I want insert the text into database.

I'm sorry for my language

Attach file : http://www.sscic.org/code.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **layout.js**:

Find:

```
onChange: function(formated) {
    $('#widgetField span').get(0).innerHTML = formated.join(' &divide; ');
}
```

Replace with:

```
onChange: function(formated) {
    $('#widgetField input[type=text]').get(0).value = formated.join(' - ');
}
```

---

Open **index.html**

Find:

```
<span>28 July, 2008 &divide; 31 July, 2008</span>
```

Replace with:

```
<input type="text" name="selectdate" />
```

Now your input has a name, you may also want to style the input field too. ;)

Comment: I suggest you to select this answer the accepted solution. Thanks.